# What is the Ruby way of integrating a lookup table into a form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, coding-style

I am new to Rails. I know there are similar questions out there on this, but I cannot find hits exactly what I'm looking for. I have a "roles" lookup table in my RoR app that stores the type of roles that a user can have, e.g "Admin", "Super Admin", "User" etc. Right now the way I am managing this when a user is created is to have radio boxes with the given roles like this:

```
  <%= f.label :role %>
  <%= f.radio_button :role, 2%> Super User
  <%= f.radio_button :role, 3 %> Admin
  <%= f.radio_button :role, 4 %> User
```

These numbers, 2,3,4 correspond to ids in the Role table

And then in my users_controller I do:

```
def create
    @user = User.new
    @user.email = user_params[:email]
    @user.firstname = user_params[:firstname]
    @user.lastname = user_params[:lastname]
    @user.password = user_params[:password]
    @user.password_confirmation = user_params[:password_confirmation]
    @user.role = Role.find(user_params[:role])

    if @user.save
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

Because doing "@user = User.new(user_params)" throws an error correctly informing me that a "Role" was expected, not an int.

Even my novice eyes can see that even though this works it is not right and I am wondering if someone could tell me the proper way to do it.

Thanks!

Comment: why not rename the input to `role_id`?

Comment: Are you storing role in the database as a string?

Comment: Yes, role is a string in the database. What part of the input do you think I should change to role_id?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Radio buttons for a has\_many and belongs\_to association](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686644/radio-buttons-for-a-has-many-and-belongs-to-association)

Comment: That question does not address how to assign back the values collected through the radio button. My question is also how to make the assignment code in my controller more elegant/rubyish.

Comment: I've added an answer that should address the concerns you just listed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686644/radio-buttons-for-a-has-many-and-belongs-to-association), you can add radio buttons for your role table as follows:

```
<% Role.all.each do |r| %>
  <%= f.radio_button :role_id, r.id %>
  <%= f.label :role_id, r.name %>
<% end %>
```

Then, you simply need to permit `:role_id` rather than `:role` in your `user_params`, and you should be good to go.

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
 def create
   @user = User.new(user_params)

   if @user.save
     flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
     redirect_to @user
   else
     render 'new'
   end
 end


  private
    def user_params
      # permit :role_id
      params.require(:user).permit(:email, :firstname:, :lastname, :role_id, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

That happens when you have done something like:

```
class User
  #etc
  has_one :role
end
```

This creates a setter #role=, but expects an instance of Role as argument. You can use #role_id= instead as others pointed out. You could do this:

```
<%= form_for current_user do |f| %>
  <%= f.select :role_id, Role.all %>
<% end %>
```